# Bounds of an imageView in a scrollView with rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frame, bounds

I have a full screen UIScrollView to display my image, which employ some codes from PhotoScroller.app from apple sample code. I am little confused on the bounds of a imageView in a scrollView with rotation, and the convertPoint. Any help will be appreciated!

ps. For more detail codes please find in [Center of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556265/center-of-bounds)

**NSLog in call willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:**

```
2012-05-12 11:35:45.666 imageScrollView frame X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000 
2012-05-12 11:35:45.672 imageScrollView frame Width and Height are 320.000000 and 480.000000 
2012-05-12 11:35:45.677 imageScrollView bounds origin X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000 
2012-05-12 11:35:45.682 imageScrollView bounds Width and Height are 320.000000 and 480.000000 
2012-05-12 11:35:45.686 imageView frame origin X and Y are 0.000005 and 0.374437
2012-05-12 11:35:45.689 imageView frame size Width and Height are 320.000000 and 479.251129
2012-05-12 11:35:45.693 imageView bounds origin X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000
2012-05-12 11:35:45.697 imageView bounds size Width and Height are 641.000000 and 959.999939
2012-05-12 11:35:45.701 boundsCenter X and Y are 160.000000 and 240.000000 
2012-05-12 11:35:45.705 convertPoint origin X and Y are 320.500000 and 479.999969
```

**NSLog in call willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:**

```
2012-05-12 11:36:05.975 imageScrollView frame X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000 
2012-05-12 11:36:05.978 imageScrollView frame Width and Height are 480.000000 and 320.000000 
2012-05-12 11:36:05.983 imageScrollView bounds origin X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000 
2012-05-12 11:36:05.987 imageScrollView bounds Width and Height are 480.000000 and 320.000000 
2012-05-12 11:36:05.990 imageView frame origin X and Y are 80.000008 and 0.000017
//I am confused here. Why is the X is 80.000008, and Y is 0.000017, but not (80, -120)?
2012-05-12 11:36:05.994 imageView frame size Width and Height are 320.000000 and 479.251099
2012-05-12 11:36:06.002 imageView bounds origin X and Y are 0.000000 and 0.000000
2012-05-12 11:36:06.006 imageView bounds size Width and Height are 641.000000 and 959.999878
2012-05-12 11:36:06.009 boundsCenter X and Y are 240.000000 and 160.000000 
2012-05-12 11:36:06.014 convertPoint origin X and Y are 320.500000 and 320.499969
```

**About the autoresizing configuration:**

```
actionSheetCoverView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
imageScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

**The imageview frame origin before rotate (NSLog in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration) is (0, 0) , after rotate (NSLog in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:), i think it should be (80, -120). But it is (80.000008, 0.000017);**

Comment: You do not say what you are confused about and you do not say why you want to get the center of the bounds so it is really hard to help you out here.

Comment: @MichaelFrederick I have update the post, plz check.

Comment: Is the problem after rotation with scrollView content size?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi The content size is image.size, never changed after the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame` property always returns a *calculated* value based on the `bounds`, `center`, and  `transform` properties of a UIView.

As per Apple's [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5):

> If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of the `frame` property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

The problem is that you're reading the `frame` property at the start of a rotation animation, which means your views will have a non-identity `transform` value, making their `frame` values meaningless.

You can log the transform values like so, based on the code from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556265/center-of-bounds):

```
NSLog(@"imageScrollView transform %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.transform));

NSLog(@"imageView transform %@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(imageView.transform));
```

This will show you the transform property at the time of rotation.  If you're not familiar with the Identity Transform, it's `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

In other words, the reason the `frame` property is giving you unexpected values is because your view has a `transform` applied to it, rendering the `frame` property meaningless.

It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve, but this other note from the same Apple documentation may be of help:

> If the `transform` property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the `frame` property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the `center` property and adjust the size using the `bounds` property instead.

Comment: 2012-05-19 16:47:27.495 imageScrollView transform [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2012-05-19 16:47:27.499 imageView transform [0.49922, 0, 0, 0.49922, 0, 0]   . It is also identity transform but with a scale 0.49922 right?

Comment: Right, and that explains the frame value you're seeing, as well as the value from convertPoint:toView: (it's returning a point in the original non-transformed coordinates of the image view).

Comment: So rendering the frame property IS NOT meaningless. Right? Then why imageView frame origin are (80.000008, 0.000017)? I think the origin.y should be negative. The rotation should be around the center of the screen, right?

Comment: The documentation says that it's meaningless, and that you should use the 'center' property instead, but in your case it's quite obvious where the value are coming from.  UIScrollView is responsible for setting the origin (or center) of its subviews.  You should override the [UIScrollView layoutSubviews] to see how and when it positions its subviews, and you can use that method to reposition your ImageView manually if desired.  Note that this method is called whenever any scrolling occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained, it is hard to help you out when you don't say why you are confused or what you are attempting to do.

To get the actual center of the imageView, you can use this:

```
imageView.center
```

Comment: I am confused here. Why imageView frame origin are (80.000008, 0.000017), but not (80, -120)?